# Highcharts series line width is not stable

Tags: charts, highcharts

```
events: {
  click: function (event) {
    this.lineWidth=5;
  }
}
```

This is Highcharts series click event function. I set this series width 5 in here. It works when I do click on series but as I removed my mouse from series. Series width goes back to normal. I want this width to be stable what I set in click event. Until I don't change i.t

Comment: I would suggest providing a fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You're not updating the chart config by doing that - you need to use series.update() if you want the change to be permanent.

Comment: Series.Update method worked for same.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can use Series.update() method in case of your chart. Here you can find information about this method:
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.update

```
    $(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        events: {
          click: function(event) {
            this.update({
              lineWidth: 5
            })
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'ADBE',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }]
  });
});
```

And here you can find simple example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/5u6anyzb/3/

Best regards.

Comment: Happy to read that it worked for you. If you think this is a correct answer for your question, could you please accept it as an answer?